# Delphi FindVCLWindow returning nil

Tags: windows, delphi, mousewheel

My application uses mouse wheel scrolling in a number of places.

Thus I’ve written a mouse wheel handler, and this handler works out where the mouse is located before calling the appropriate object method.

On most PCs this works fine, but I have one laptop here where it does not. Despite the handler receiving the correct mouse co-ordinates from Windows, calls to FindVCLWindow are returning nil. This is however only happening when I use the laptop’s internal touch pad. External USB mice work fine.

I’ve updated the laptop’s touch pad driver to the latest available from the manufacturer's web site, but to no avail.

How else can I fix this?

Here’s the code:

```
unit Mouse_Wheel_Testing;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Grids;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    Mouse_Coordinates: TEdit;
    Control_Name: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure MouseWheelHandler(var Message: TMessage); override;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.MouseWheelHandler(var Message: TMessage);
var
  Target_Control: TWinControl;
begin
  with TWMMouseWheel(Message) do
  begin
    Mouse_Coordinates.Text := IntToStr(XPos) + ', ' + IntToStr(YPos);
    Target_Control := FindVCLWindow(Point(XPos, YPos));
    if Target_Control <> nil then
      Control_Name.Text := Target_Control.Name
    else
      Control_Name.Text := 'nil';
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: So the coordinates are wrong, then? If so, what returns e.g. `GetMessagePos` function?

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: The coordinates appear to be correct, but FindVCLWindow is returning nil. That is what I can't understand.

Comment: Further: the coordinates appear to be correct, in that both the touch pad and USB mouse return the same coordinates. However, when I call FindVCLWindow in response to the mouse it returns the correct component, but when I call it in response to the touch pad, it returns nil.

Comment: So do some debugging. Why does FindVCLWindow return nil? The vast majority of questions here could be progressed by debugging. On a meta level, what you need is not a solution to this problem. What you need is to learn how to debug this problem.

Comment: What do you use to simulate/emulate the mouse wheel on the tuch pad? Does the `MouseWheelHandler()` procedure fire?

Comment: I am using the actual touch pad, and yes, it does fire the MouseWheelHandler. I've now checked all the parameters in Message, and they are identical, and yet when called in response to the mouse I get the correct control, but when called in response to the touch pad I get nil. Thus something is happening outside my app which (presumably) I need to change.

Comment: And you aren't prepared to debug this?

Comment: I would be happy to if I knew how. Since this appears to be "outside Delphi", setting break points and all the other debugging tools that are included as part of the Delphi IDE don't apply.

Comment: The next obvious place to look would be in the source code for FindCVLWindow, but I haven't been able to find this.

Comment: P.S. I'm using the "Standard" version of Delphi, and it would appear that the VCL source code is only included with the "Professional" version.

Comment: `FindVCLWindow` is in the Controls unit. How can you *not* be able to find it? Click the function name to select it, right-click, choose *Find declaration* from the context menu, and the IDE will open the file and take you directly to the code.

Comment: I have already tried that, and nothing happened. At this stage I'm assuming that's because the standard version of Delphi (which is what I'm using) doesn't include the VCL source code.

Comment: I have also searched my hard drive, and all I can find is Controls.int which is the declarations (no implementation section) plus Controls.dcu.

Comment: (from 2006 pro version - hth, sorry can't format it)
    function FindVCLWindow(const Pos: TPoint): TWinControl;
    var
      Handle: HWND;
    begin
      Handle := WindowFromPoint(Pos);
      Result := nil;
      while Handle <> 0 do
      begin
        Result := FindControl(Handle);
        if Result <> nil then Exit;
        Handle := GetParent(Handle);
      end;
    end;

Comment: Yeah, you are knackered without source.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's most appreciated. I can now trace this issue by adding a local FindVCLWindow function to my app.

Comment: If you're using something other than the standard (Pro or higher SKU) Delphi, you should mention that in your post. And if you want to reply to a specific person, use @ plus that person's name.

Comment: It seems that WindowFromPoint doesn’t return the correct handle when using the laptop’s touch pad. Since there’s only a few controls that I’m actually interested in, I’m going to write my own ControlFromPoint function.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why FindVCLWindow was returning nil was that WindowFromPoint was returning an incorrect handle. This in turn was the result of a setting in the laptop relating to the behavior of its touch pad when in scrolling mode. This option needed to be set correctly for the correct handle to be returned.

Since my application cannot rely on the user having their laptop set correctly, I have now written a new FindComponent function which is based upon ChildWindowFromPointEx. The following function now resides within the mouse wheel handler:

```
function Find_Control: TWinControl;
var
  Parent: HWND;
  Child: HWND;
  Position: TPoint;
begin { Find_Control }
  Result := nil;
  Parent := Self.Handle;
  with TWMMouseWheel(Message) do
    Position := ScreenToClient(Point(XPos, YPos));
  Child := ChildWindowFromPointEx(Parent, Position, CWP_SKIPINVISIBLE);
  while (Child <> 0) and (Child <> Parent) do
  begin
    Result := FindControl(Child);
    Position := Point(Position.X - Result.Left, Position.Y - Result.Top);
    Parent := Child;
    Child := ChildWindowFromPointEx(Parent, Position, CWP_SKIPINVISIBLE);
  end; { while (Child <> 0) and (Child <> Parent) }
end; { Find_Control }
```